# how to shift a datetime object by 12 hours in python

Tags: python, datetime

Datetime objects hurt my head for some reason. I am writing to figure out how to shift a date time object by 12 hours. I also need to know how to figure out if two date time object's differ by say 1 minute or more.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) library has a `timedelta` object specifically for this kind of thing:

```
import datetime

mydatetime = datetime.now() # or whatever value you want
twelvelater = mydatetime + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
twelveearlier = mydatetime - datetime.timedelta(hours=12)

difference = abs(some_datetime_A - some_datetime_B)
# difference is now a timedelta object

# there are a couple of ways to do this comparision:
if difference > timedelta(minutes=1):
    print "Timestamps were more than a minute apart"

# or: 
if difference.total_seconds() > 60:
    print "Timestamps were more than a minute apart"
```

Comment: It can fail if utc offset changes for the local timezone e.g., during DST transitions. Date arithmetic is more convenient to perform using UTC timezone, and converting it to a local time only to display it to a user

Answer (score 5):

You'd use `datetime.timedelta` for something like this.

```
from datetime import timedelta
```

`datetime` arithmetic works kind of like normal arithmetic: you can add a `timedelta` object to a `datetime` object to shift its time:

```
dt = # some datetime object
dt_plus_12 = dt + timedelta(hours=12)
```

Also you can subtract two `datetime` objects to get a `timedelta` representing the difference between them:

```
dt2 = # some other datetime object
ONE_MINUTE = timedelta(minutes=1)
if abs(dt2 - dt) > ONE_MINUTE:
    # do something
```