# Using python-twitter library, how to set timezone?

Tags: python, twitter, timezone, python-twitter

I'm trying to list out tweets with their time-stamps. I have this...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import twitter
api = twitter.Api()
statuses = api.GetUserTimeline('ttytter')
for s in statuses:
  print s.created_at + " " + s.text
```

Which prints out...

`Sat Oct 20 04:56:47 +0000 2012 @uriel1998 W/r/t DMs, they appear just fine in 2.0.4 and 2.1 beta here, near as I can tell.`

Which is pretty much what I'm after, but for the time, which seems to be in the wrong timezone. https://twitter.com/ttytter/status/259518502069760000

Is there a way I can change this within the python-twitter library? I was looking at  [GetTimeZone() and SetTimeZone()](http://static.unto.net/python-twitter/0.6/doc/twitter.html), but I haven't been able to figure out how they work.

Also looking at [how to shift a datetime object by 12 hours in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660210/how-to-shift-a-datetime-object-by-12-hours-in-python) but not sure if I need to go there.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: do you want to convert utc time to tweet's author timezone or your local timezone?

Comment: In this case, they are the same, and I'm ok with setting it manually. Probably, it would be a better script if it used the author's timezone, though.

Comment: If it is not part of the question then you could post the code as an answer to allow independent voting, commenting, small fixes that are not appropriate if it is a part of the question e.g., `st_tz` stands for Stockholm timezone in my code, it could replaced by `la_tz`, `user_tz`, `local_tz` whatever more appropriate in your case (same for `st_dt`)

Comment: Ok, put it as its own answer. Thanks for pointing out the variable convention you're using. I will edit my code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[python-twitter](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter) returns the status timestamps as a string and as the number of seconds since the epoch. The latter is the simplest to convert to a timezone-aware [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) instance (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691081/from-a-timezone-and-a-utc-time-get-the-difference-in-seconds-vs-local-time-at-t)).

Unfortunately the user's `time_zone` attribute is not in the standard [tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) format used by [`pytz`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/), so it is necessary to use the `utc_offset` user attribute instead (we still use the `time_zone` attribute to name the [`tzinfo`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) created with with the UTC offset). The [`python-dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package provides a convenience type `tzoffset` that allows the creation of [`tzinfo`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) instances from UTC offsets, which we can then use to convert the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) from UTC to the local time zone:

```
import pytz
import twitter

from datetime import  datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzoffset

USERNAME = 'ttytter'

api = twitter.Api()

# get a 'tzinfo' instance with the UTC offset for the user's local time
user = api.GetUser(USERNAME)
localtime_tz = tzoffset(user.time_zone, user.utc_offset)

statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(USERNAME)
for s in statuses[:1]:
    # get UTC timestamp from seconds since epoch
    utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(s.created_at_in_seconds).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    print('utc: {}'.format(utc_dt))
    # convert to local time in the user's timezone
    localtime_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(localtime_tz)
    print('localtime [{}]: {}'.format(localtime_dt.tzname(), localtime_dt))
```

which gives the output for the first status:

```
utc: 2012-10-20 04:56:47+00:00
localtime [Pacific Time (US & Canada)]: 2012-10-19 20:56:47-08:00
```

Comment: you don't need `dateutil`. python-twitter provides `created_at_in_seconds` that you could convert to a time in given timezone using [the pytz example I've linked above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12692910/4279).

Comment: You're absolutely right @J.F.Sebastian. Thanks. Revising the answer.

Comment: How does dateutil.tzoffset-based code account for DST transitions?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: it doesn't. I just assume that Twitter calculates the correct UTC offset for the local timezone and timestamp taking into account any DST transitions. I would prefer to use just `pytz`, but how can we get a `pytz` timezone from just the UTC offset? The `time_zone` attribute is useless because it doesn't contain proper Olson timezone names.

Comment: Thanks Pedro and J.F.! By combining your answers I've got exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

Combining suggestions from Pedro Romano and J.F. Sebastian, I have this...

```
import pytz
import twitter

from datetime import  datetime

USERNAME = 'ttytter'

api = twitter.Api()

user = api.GetUser(USERNAME)
pst_tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')

statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(USERNAME)
for s in statuses[:1]:
    # get UTC timestamp from seconds since epoch
    utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(s.created_at_in_seconds).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    # convert to given timezone
    pst_dt = pst_tz.normalize(utc_dt.astimezone(st_tz))
    print(pst_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ')) + s.text
```

Output: `2012-10-19 21:56:47 @uriel1998 W/r/t DMs, they appear just fine in 2.0.4 and 2.1 beta here, near as I can tell.` which is the correct time zone and also accounts for DST.

Thank you!